# is F differentiable at x0,y0

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$F(x,y)=(x^2-y,xy)$, how to show that F is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$ and find $dF(x_0,y_0)$

My attempt:
I think I understand part 2 of this question,

$dF=\begin{pmatrix} 2x & -1 \\ y & x \end{pmatrix}$ and just plug $x_0,y_0$

but how to show f is differentiable at $x_0,y_0$?

Comment: Do you already know that $\color{grey}{F=}(f_1, f_2)$ is differentiable if, and only if, $f_1$ and $f_2$ are? Do you know that polynomials are differentiable scalar functions?

Comment: @GitGud It certainly seems $f_1$ and $f_2$ are differentiable but I'm not sure how to prove it.  And what do you mean polynomials are differentiable scalar functions?

Comment: Do you know what a scalar function is? What is your definition of differentiability?

Comment: @GitGud Is a scalar function one which takes $\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$?  Definition of differentiability is taking $h \rightarrow 0$ of (f(x+h)-f(x))/h?

Comment: Yes, it is. So do you know understand what I meant with polynomials being differentiable scalar functions? Are you asking ME for the definition? You're the one who's supposed to tell me. The definition you provided is for one-variable functions only.

Comment: @GitGud Yes because for instance $f_1$ takes $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$.  So now I understand what you mean about scalar functions.  I think I have a definition for multivariable differentials here $h \rightarrow 0$ of $(f(x+he_j)-f(x))/h$... So applying this to my case I need to take this definition on each component of F(x,y)?

Comment: Nope, that's the definition of directional derivative.

Comment: @GitGud I see.  I think perhaps this is the correct definition, $h \rightarrow 0$ of $(F(a+h)-F(a)-L(h))/||h||$.  Let me see if I can apply to this my case

Comment: Now it's getting closer to correct,but you're missing some stuff.

Comment: @GitGud I'm not sure what I am missing but I think I am going to take a crack at it and will post my answer later for verification

Comment: A function $g$ is said to be differentiable at $X_0$ if, and only if, there exists a linear map $L\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ such that $$\lim \limits_{H\to 0_{\mathbb R^n}}\left(\dfrac{g(X_0+H)-g(X_0)-L(H)}{\|H\|}\right)=0_{\mathbb R^m}.$$
This linear map $L$ is denoted by $(Dg)(X_0)$ and it is called the [differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of $g$ at $X_0$. You were missing the existential quantifier on $L$ and the fact that the limit must be $0$.

Comment: It's an existential statement. What $L$ should you take? It's the map determined by the jacobian matrix ($dF(x,y)$) in the standard basis.

Comment: @GitGud I understand a lot better now.  I will be working on this problem for the next little while